# joining mysql subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I'm accessing data on my site with 3 queries, first query gets a full listing of deals available on the site:

```
  $listingquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE city = '$city' AND approved = '1' 
  AND enddate > NOW() ORDER BY id DESC";
```

next query gets the count/list of available deal providers:

```
  $providerquery = "SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE 
  city = '$city' AND approved='1' AND enddate > NOW() GROUP BY provider";
```

and 3rd query gets the count/list of categories from available deal providers in that city:

```
  $categoryquery = "SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE 
  city = '$city' AND approved='1' AND enddate > NOW() GROUP BY category";
```

is there a way to combine all that into 1 query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's something funny about your second query: did you mean to select the `provider` column instead of `category`?  Also, you're not grouping by `programname` in either the second or the third query; MySQL allows this, but may return random results unless each provider/category is guaranteed to have only one program name.

Comment: yea that was a typo as was trying to do 15 things at once, its grouped by programname

Answer (score 0):

You might get some lossless information but you can try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) 
     FROM table 
     WHERE city = '$city' AND approved='1' AND enddate > NOW() GROUP BY provider
  ) b ON a.provider = b.provider
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) 
     FROM table 
     WHERE city = '$city' AND approved='1' AND enddate > NOW() GROUP BY category
  ) c ON a.category = b.category
  WHERE a.city = '$city' AND a.approved = '1' 
    AND a.enddate > NOW() 
  ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

---

Update with one Where clause (somewhat):

```
 SELECT * FROM table a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) 
     FROM table 
     WHERE enddate > NOW() GROUP BY provider
  ) b ON a.provider = b.provider
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  programname, category, COUNT(name) 
     FROM table 
     WHERE enddate > NOW() GROUP BY category
  ) c ON a.category = b.category
  WHERE a.city = '$city' AND a.approved = '1' 
    AND a.enddate > NOW() 
    AND b.city = a.city AND c.city = a.city
    AND b.approved = a.approved AND c.approved = a.approved
  ORDER BY a.id DESC;
```

Comment: can i join and break it down where the WHERE variables are only defined once?  seems redundant to me.  I'm still new to this so am trying to learn as quickly as possible the right way to do things.

Comment: @Mike my most recent update might **not** be the way to go. but it is correct in some aspects

Comment: do i have to drastically change my while loop to pull the data?  seems to be working fine for the main listings, categories/providers dont pull any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that all this is possible/feasible in single query but either way you should not use sub-query in MySQL, it will drastically degrade performance. Prefer joins instead of sub-query.

Comment: I think my terminology was off.  Neals answer seems to be the most logical for my use, just trying to make it work now :)